# Can I set an Image to a Relative Layout?

Tags: android, image, android-relativelayout

I have two relative layouts together, and I want to set an `Image` (drawable from resources) to one of the layouts programmatically. The image cannot be a background image. I have tried using `setBackgroundResource()` but that doesn't serve the purpose. Is there a method which could set a foreground image to my layout?

Comment: Try ImageView. <http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use ImageView.

```
Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tnj1);

ImageView img = new ImageView(your_activity_name.this);
img.setImageBitmap(bmp1);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imgParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
img.setLayoutParams(imgParams);
YOUR_RELATIVE_LAYOUT.addView(img);
```

Comment: My class does not extend Activity class. What should be the context then?

Comment: If you are creating instance of this from any activity, then you can pass context from that activity through constructor (or other way, like putting method for passing context..)

Comment: and when do I get the error `getResources()` is not defined for the type myclass

Comment: Use  **passed_context.getResources()**

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do the trick:

```
ImageView img_view = new ImageView(context);
img_view.setImageDrawable(your_image_here);
img_view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
layout.addView(img_view);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an ImageView child to the layout with `match_parent` height and width attributes and then set the image to that ImageView.